# Disable/Hide text selection context-menu on Android WebView generated by Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, webview, ionic-framework, contextmenu

I am trying to disable, remove or hide the context menu that appears when highlighting text natively in android. https://i.stack.imgur.com/caUOw.png (My reputation is too low to include it in this post :P) The top right button on the green header is intended to be the selectable context menu in the app. The native context menu appearing lags the app and confuses the user's experience based on testing.

I've tried:

Overriding ActionMode.Callback in the cordova generated MainActivity. After accessing the menu (mode.getMenu()) I could clear it(menu.clear()) https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9chW.png. But! menu.close() does not close the context menu.

Creating an empty menu view and calling the action mode's menu inflater on the empty menu.

-webkit-touch-callout: none; in the javascript.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following code to your CSS stylesheet should prevent this behavior in a WebView:

```
body {
  -webkit-user-select: none;                  /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
}
```

Unsure if you're looking to disable in a WebView or in native UI components.

Comment: I am looking to disable this in a WebView in Android specifically. -webkit-user-select: none; can't be the solution, because we need the user to be able to select text.

I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Ah I see. Sadly I know very little on the native side. I prob won't be much help here then. You may want to try to rephrase your question so that it's clearer what you are asking and hopefully more people will try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even thoush this is an old question, i wanted to share my solution because it took me quite a while to figure out.

Catch the 'contextmenu' event and preventDefault().

```
<input style="text" oncontextmenu="e=>e.preventDefault()"/>
```

or

```
myHtmlElement.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => e.preventDefault())
```